# Multiple regressions with subsets of data using dplyr in R

Tags: r, regression, dplyr

I have a data frame "DF" with this `glimpse()`:

```
Observations: 1244160
Variables:
$ Test      (fctr) 72001.txt, 72002.txt, 72003.txt, 72004.txt, 72005.txt,...
$ x         (int) 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...
$ y         (int) 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2...
$ Value     (dbl) -77.111111, -13.111111, 13.888889, 235.888889, 138.8888...
```

For each Test, I want to **model** "Value" using a **subset** of the data:

1. The  function: Value ~ x + y
2. The data: (x, y) / 0 < x < 6, 0 < y < 6

Then, I want to **predict** the "Value" for **all the data** in "DF" using these models.

For these calculations, I want to use `dplyr`. However, I don't find the way to do it. This was my last try:

```
DF %>% 
    group_by(Test) %>% 
    do({
        mod = lm(Value ~ x + y, data = (. %>% filter((x > 0) &  (x < 6) & (y > 0) & (y < 6))))
        print(mod)
        Pred <- predict(mod, .)
        data.frame(. , Pred)
    })
glimpse()
```

But it's failing. Can you help me?

**Reproducible example**

To test answers, we can use a dummy reproducible data frame, e.g., mtcars:

```
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    do({ 
        mod = lm(mpg ~ wt + qsec, data = . %>% filter(vs == 0))
        print(mod)
        Pred <- predict(mod)
        data.frame(. , Pred)
    })
glimpse()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I have an answer, that was close to my try:

```
results <- mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    do({ 
        mod = lm(mpg ~ wt + qsec, data = filter(., vs == 0))
        print(mod)
        Pred <- predict(mod, .)
        data.frame(. , Pred)
    })

print(results, n=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `subset` argument of `lm` function.

```
results <- DF %>% 
           group_by(Test) %>% 
           do(mod = lm(Value ~ x + y, data = ., subset = foo))
```

To generate predicted values try this:

```
predict <- results %>% 
           do(data.frame(pred = predict(.$mod), Test = .[["Test"]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `filter` before `group_by`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  filter(vs==0) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  do({ 
    mod = lm(mpg ~ wt + qsec, data = .)
    Pred <- predict(mod)
    data.frame(Pred)
  })
```

Non `dplyr` solution:

```
lapply(split(mtcars,mtcars$cyl), function(i){
  mod <- lm(mpg ~ wt + qsec, i[i$vs == 0,])
  Pred <- predict(mod)
  data.frame(Pred)
  })
```